# With SDV, I want to generate vertical oriented data (1 record is spread over multiple rows), is this possible?

Tags: row, synthetic, sdv

I want to generate synthetic data with SDV where each row contains only one variable name (and variable value).
Something like: PersonId, ValueName, Value, Index
I get this data from a supplier.
The dataSet per PersonId can have more than 300 fields at most.
The dataSet per PersonId can have less than 20 fields at minimum.

A person can have one or more firstnames (index 1, 2, 3 or more).
A person can have only one last name (index = 1).
A person can have one or more employers (and salary) (index 1, 2, ...)
(The index keeps data together (unique index for employer, salary)

And the personId keeps all the records for a person together.

Is SDV capable of generating such a dataset?
My outcome till now is not that convincing.

I just started simple by importing a small dataset (20 records) to see if there was an output which could convince me. But the result was not that great (than again, I don't know what the best approach is).